# glReadPixels with FBO is too slow

Tags: opengl-es, framebuffer, glreadpixels

I am using openGL ES 2.0 and GLSL shader and working on FBO with Renderbuffer, aka offscreen rendering. 
It works fine with **30 fps**.
But when I use glReadPixels or glcopyteximage2d, it drops to **8 fps**.
I did something like:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuf);
//DRAW something
glReadPixels(...); //HERE
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Is there anyway I can improve the speed? I mean when I don't use FBO and use glReadPixels with same parameters, it works **15 fps** and I thought using FBO could improve the speed?

Comment: Are you copying your offscreen render to the screen using `glReadPixels()`, etc? If you're rendering to a surface, why not do it directly (or as close as can be - I've never use OpenGL ES).

Comment: Yes, so I am using glsl shader and whatever the fragment shader outputs, I have to access/read framebuffer so that I can compute something. My idle goal is to read framebuffer, offscreen, do something, then draw the final on-screen

Comment: So, make 2 textures, bind one to the FBO, and the other as input texture. Then switch FBOs with the 2nd one bound and use the 1st as texture. Don't copy. (If ES supports that -- I don't know out of my hand whether it does -- you can also bind both of them to the FBO and as texture, and decide via an uniform which texture to read, and disable color writes in the other MRT. For correctness, though it normally "still works" if you put "something else" in between ping and pong, you need to synchronize so caches are written out before data is being read in again, such as with NV_texture_barrier).

Comment: possible duplicate of [FBO offscreen rendering slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634940/fbo-offscreen-rendering-slow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bad (very bad) way to get OpenGL data (using any of `glGet***` functions). To copy texture or some it's part to screen/other texture you may draw it with quad. If you need pixels data for some logical processing, it would be better to make framebuffer as small as possible and read it only when necessary.